# Securing Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

This is my first time using Drupal and I am loving it, but there are a lot of configurations to go through (which I love) and I am afraid there is something I need to enable/disable to make Drupal production ready. I did see that printing errors to the screen is enabled by default so that is why I am asking if there is anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Drupal Administration Guide](http://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration) in the handbook does a pretty decent job at going through what you want to look out for. You'll also want to subscribe to the [Drupal Security mailing list](http://drupal.org/security) to keep track of contrib and core vulnerabilities.

Comment: forgot about that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From a more practical point of view Drupal is *secure* out of the box but being a CMS means that the settings may not be suitable for your personal site. For example the default account settings are to let people visiting your site create accounts by themselves, so you might want to disable that.

Here are some configuration settings that you might want to check (These are for Drupal 7):

Select if visitors can create accounts etc.
/admin/config/people/accounts

Check all the permissions that relate to you. Sensible defaults are set like anonymous users can view comments, and published content.
/admin/people/permissions

Text Formats. These have sensible defaults but check to make sure roles are not setup to use php input format (this should really never be set in my opinion).
/admin/config/content/formats

Error logging.
/admin/config/development/logging

Also check your file permissions to make sure they are in line with the suggestions on drupal.org - http://drupal.org/node/244924

It's worth remembering to look at your site as an anonymous user - I know that sounds obvious but a lot of people stay logged in as user 1 and don't realise how the site might look to someone who is of another role or not logged in at all. Use another browser to view the site so you can keep logged in as one user and anonymous in the other browser.

If you are going to be writing modules look into the api functions like filter_xss() and checkplain() - http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is secure by default.

Just make sure your settings.php is protected in the file structure.

The error messages only appear for the admin normally, but you can remove them from the non-admin theme if you prefer (comment them in code).

You probably also want some kind of spammer protection, such as the mollom module.

And make regular backups (backup and migrate module).

For more tips: [Drupal Ultimate Community Site Guide](http://book.drupalfun.com).